# compute the gradient line of edge pixel

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to compute the gradient line of some pixels in the detected contour. the detected contour example is
[detected contour figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOBDz.png).
To do so I first compute image gradient using the following code

```
img_sobelx = cv2.Sobel(grey_img,cv2.CV_16S,1,0,ksize=3)
img_sobely = cv2.Sobel(grey_img,cv2.CV_16S,0,1,ksize=3)
m = np.hypot(img_sobelx,img_sobelx)
```

then I use the following code to find the gradient line of some pixels in the contour
Note: to detect the contour I use canny edge method and the connected component

```
px,py =np.where(img > 0)   # img: is the example image (after detecting the contour)
# pick points from the curve
index = np.array(range(0,py.shape[0],int(py.shape[0]/10)))
for i in index[:-1]:
     #first line
     m1 = m[px[i],py[i]]    #slope
     b1 = py[i] - (m1*px[i]) # intercept
     for j in index[k:]:
          m2 = m[px[j],py[j]]
          b2 = py[j] - (m2*px[j])
          # intersection point
          if (m2-m1) == 0:
               continue
          xi = (b1-b2) / (m2-m1)
          yi = m1 * xi + b1
          start_point = (py[i],px[i])
          end_point = (int(yi),int(xi))
          img= cv2.line(img,start_point,end_point,(255,255,255),1)
          start_point = (py[j],px[j])
          end_point = (int(yi),int(xi))
          img= cv2.line(img,start_point,end_point,(255,255,255),1)
```

the output of the above code is
[output: gradient line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/599C1.png)

The result seems not correct. Could you please help me to find the correct method?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `img_sobelx` and `img_sobely` as the two components of the vector. The hypotenuse is not the slope of this vector, it is the magnitude. The magnitude says how strong the gradient is, not what direction it is in.

If you have a point `(px[i],py[i])`, then the point `(px[i]+img_sobelx[i],py[i]+img_sobely[i])` is a second point on the line you are looking for.